# How to compare string is javascript?

Tags: javascript

The question link is:
http://www.codewars.com/kata/529eef7a9194e0cbc1000255/train/javascript

> An anagram is the result of rearranging the letters of a word to
>   produce a new word. (Ref wikipedia).
>
> Note: anagrams are case insensitive
>
> Examples
>
> foefet is an anagram of toffee Buckethead is an anagram of DeathCubeK
>   The challenge is to write the function isAnagram (or is_anagram in
>   Python) to return true if the word test is an anagram of the word
>   original and false otherwise. The function prototype is as given
>   below:

My answer is:

```
// write the function isAnagram
var isAnagram = function(test, orig) {
  var test = test.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');
  var orig = orig.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');

  return test == orig;
};
```

But when i commit this code, i got this error:

```
Test didn't pass: Unknown error
Process took 71ms to complete
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with your code, can you put a break point in an see if your code is being called correctly? Can add a URL of the code challenge - assuming its an online thing...

Comment: Nothing. Need more information at this point.

Comment: @Adam Here is the link:http://www.codewars.com/kata/529eef7a9194e0cbc1000255/train/javascript

Comment: @BlackMamba There is literally nothing wrong with your code. It is a an issue with the test runner.

Comment: @jdphenix it is my implement is to slow?

Comment: @BlackMamba I doubt it. Your code passed their test runner from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet is failing for the test case

- Test with null strings
- Test with one valid and another null string

you'll get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
```

Comment: True, but not applicable - OPs code passes the test runner from where they got the code challenge

Answer (score 0):

What were your arguments? Whose test didn’t pass? The latter depends, but regarding arguments, the [function actually works](http://jsfiddle.net/eg0q3bqd/1/) with strings, yet a type check might be in order:

```
if(typeof test != 'string' || typeof orig != 'string')
    return false; // “return false otherwise”
```